# primeng datatable hangs for just 2000 records

Tags: primeng, angular

I am using [primeng datatable](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable) with angular 4. It is working properly for static data but when i am trying to bind data from server it has almost 10000 records and datatable fails to load. Even if i cut down it to 2000 records which has only one field "name" it still fails to load.

I don't know if it is not providing support for just 1000's of records?